# How to remove the key and value from single and multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here, my array is sometimes 1D or 2D. From my array, I need to remove some of the keys. Lets say for now my array is like below:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "picture_id" => "1"
    "color_name" => "Black"
    "color_code" => "#000000"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "picture_id" => "1"
    "color_name" => "Red"
    "color_code" => "#ff0000"
  ]
]
```

I have following lines of code, here I check if the array is 1D or 2D. And based on that, I am trying to unset my array.

```
$remainingArray = Helpers::removedSelectedKeys($groupedInputs, ["picture_id"]);

public static function removedSelectedKeys(array $array, array $keys)
{
    array_map(function ($key) use (&$array) {
        if (Helpers::isMulti($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $item) {
                unset($item[$key]);
            }
        } elseif (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }, $keys);
    return $array;
}

public static function isMulti($array)
{
    return (count($array) != count($array, 1));
}
```

But its not working. Can anybody please help what mistake I am doing?

Comment: What is your expected array?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: From my above array, I need to remove `picture_id`

Comment: So you always want to remove picture_id?

Comment: It depends, i just add 3 fields in my array. I may have to remove more than 1 field. Thats why I passing it as an array

Comment: I find the code quite confusing but it's probably just because I'm tired, but I believe the problem is the missing `&` in the foreach. `foreach($arr as &$item){`

Comment: @Andreas sorry for writing the confusing code. :)

Comment: @Andreas is correct: https://3v4l.org/r4Mnk.